# Google MCF API - Getting data after 10:00UTC+2

Tags: cron, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api

I made a python script that call several Google Ads API to get some data. Everything is working well when I develop it but when I launch it with a cron job on a server early in the morning I was surprise to didn't have any error in my monitoring but one of the call didn't get me any data.

I tried to see if it was from my code but when I launch it from my computer everything was OK. I though about the time I launch it (around 1:00) and maybe too early.

I just figured it out that if I launch my script before 10:00 I have 0 data and after that I get some ? I'm UTC+2 so I could find out it was an issue. I cannot find a topic about what time the datas are available when you try to get them from `yesterday`.

Any idea why this happen ?

Comment: The time of the data is probably going to be assoicated with the time set of the google analytics profile.  You also have to remmber processing time.   Most google analytics data isnt done processing before 24 - 48 hours.   so you should never try to request data for yesterday.

Comment: What do you mean by - probably going to be associated with the time set of the google analytics profile.
Also the GA dashboard can give us a nearly real time view of those data, why not available via the API ?
Do you have info to link about this ?